# How to convert 2 dimensional array to Set?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, set

for the example I have `Foo` Object then I've some `Foo` Data inside 2-d Array `Foo[][]`. I want to convert it into `Set<Foo>` in order to just get Set of Foo unique data. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple (but not the best performing) solution would be to use java streams:

```
Set<Foo> set = Arrays.stream(array)
    .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

The above code snippet first creates a `Stream<Foo[]>` with the `Arrays.stream(array)` statement.

Then it flattens that stream into `Stream<Foo>` with the second statement: `.flatMap(Arrays::stream)` which behaves the same as `.flatMap(arr -> Arrays.stream(arr))`.

At last it creates a `Set<Foo>` out of the flattened stream with `.collect(Collectors.toSet())`.

I suggest having a deep look at the Java Streaming API, introduced with Java 8. It can do much more than just mapping a 2d array into a Set.

---

Another approach is just to use 2 nested for loops:

```
Set<Foo> set = new HashSet<>(); // or LinkedHashSet if you need a similar order than the array
for(Foo[] inner : array) {
    for(Foo item : inner) {
        set.add(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: @MFauzanAbdi generally java streams are slower than the "normal" for-loop solutions as the induce a significant overhead by wrapping everything into a wrapper object. In small code this is dismissable but in performant-critical code it may be the best to just use 2 nested for-loops

Comment: I see, I need to explore this Java Streaming API

Comment: `@Lino`Thanks for the help

Comment: @MFauzanAbdi you're welcome :) A tip from me is not to just always rely on streams or lambdas. As you can see, my second example is just as understandable and easy as the former. Streams are good to express *what* you want to do in your code, but the obscure *how* it is done

Comment: `@Lino` noted, I have to be careful to choose to use Streams or normal way

Answer (score 0):

```
public <T> List<T> twoDArrayToList(T[][] twoDArray) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (T[] array : twoDArray) {
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(array));
    }
    return list;
}
```